# Writing the mysql join and order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables stated following

Table `eaa`

```
--------------
| id | title |
--------------
| 1  | ABC   |
--------------
| 2  | MNO   |
--------------
| 3  | XYZ   |
```

Table `eap`

```
-----------------------
| id | eaa_id | title |
-----------------------
| 1  |  1     | CDE   |
-----------------------
| 2  |  1     | BLA   |
-----------------------
| 3  |  2     | FOO   |
----------------------
| 4  |  3     | BAR   |
-----------------------
| 5  |  3     | FOB   |
-----------------------
```

And third table `etp`

```
-----------------------------------
| id | eap_id | trip_id | dest_id |
-----------------------------------
| 1  |  1     |  143    |  104    |
-----------------------------------
| 2  |  2     |  143    |  226    |
-----------------------------------
| 3  |  3     |  143    |  226    |
-----------------------------------
| 4  |  4     |  143    |  226    |
-----------------------------------
| 5  |  5     |  143    |  228    |
-----------------------------------
| 6  |  6     |  128    |  123    |
-----------------------------------
| 7  |  7     |  442    |  154    |
```

**MY Problem**

I want to get all data from `eap` table and all data of `eaa` table against `eaa_id` in `eap` table against `trip_id` column of `etp` table and want to order by the result set in such a way that it is ordered against `dest_id` of `etp` table given in query that rows matching to given `dest_id` comes first then other rows comes later.

For example If I provide `trip_id` as 143 and `dest_id` as 226 then result should come in such a way that rows with `eap_id` 2, 3, 4 comes first then 1 and 5.

**What I have done so far**

```
 SELECT 
`eap`.* 
 FROM 
    `eap`
 LEFT JOIN 
   `eaa` 
 ON 
   eaa.id = eap.eaa_id
 LEFT JOIN 
   `etp` 
 ON 
   eap.id = etp.eap_id
 WHERE 
   (etp.trip_id = '143')
```

This query gives me all rows having eap.id where trip_id is 143. Now I am unable to understand how I will pass dest_id as 226 in query to order as I mentioned above

Comment: what a mouthful, why not just provide a simpler dataset and the desired result - preferably as an sqlfiddle or set of DDLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can add a `CASE` expression to the `ORDER BY` clause to do this. like this:

```
...
WHERE etp.trip_id = 143 or etp.dest_id = 226
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN etp.trip_id = 143 AND etp.dest_id = 226 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ID;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/729d2/3)

This will put the rows 2, 3, 4 in the first then 1, 5:

```
| ID | EAA_ID | TITLE |
|----|--------|-------|
|  2 |      1 |   BLA |
|  3 |      2 |   FOO |
|  4 |      3 |   BAR |
|  1 |      1 |   CDE |
|  5 |      3 |   FOB |
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you'd like to `ORDER BY ABS(226-dest_id)`.

Comment: Is this an answer to my question dear?

Comment: Yes. It just LOOKS LIKE a question back. It's an answer if you look closer.